# WP_Query Returns Unexpected Posts

Tags: wordpress

In the category page, I'm performing a simple query to get a post with the tag `elestiri-kategorisi-sag` which I'm sure that is used in only one post. Anyhow the query returns every post in the category before the expected post.

```
new WP_Query(array('tag_name' => 'elestiri-kategorisi-sag'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tag_name` is not a [valid parameter of WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters). You're looking for `tag`:

```
new WP_Query(array('tag' => 'elestiri-kategorisi-sag'))
```

Comment: That "easy wordpress query generator" must be for some old versions I guess. Thanks, it worked!